# Stripping '../' from the front of a string

Tags: python

I have a text file that looks like this:

`../../../../foo/bar 
../../this/that 
../barfoo`

and I want:

`foo/bar
this/that 
barfoo`

```py
 with open('file_list.txt', 'r') as file_list:
        for file_list_lines in file_list:
            file_list_lines.lstrip('../')
            print(file_list_lines)
```

I tried `.lstrip('../')` but nothing was stripped from the beginning of the line.

Comment: The simplest solution for this issue can be using split and use python filter


              "/".join(filter(lambda x: x!='..' ,file_list_lines.split('/'))))

But you can also use Python regular expression

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `string.lstrip()` does not do the string manipulation in place. In other words, you would need to store it into a variable like so:

```
stripped_line = file_list_lines.lstrip('../')
print( stripped_line )
```

In your version, you did the `lstrip`, but did not store the result of that operation anywhere.